# Having Issue On Inserting Data into MySQL Table Using jQuery Ajax and Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a JavaScript array which looks like

```
var arrLoadDb = ["M15", 
                 "1,249.99",
                 "12,585.56",
                 "277,500.00",
                 "2,312.64",
                 "6,971.06",
                 "17,953.23",
                 "48,081.03",
                 "1,560.44",
                 "7000",
                 "Cost, Population, Energy, Footprint",
                 "Black-throated Gray Warbler",
                 "Yes",
                 "Balanced",
                 "2015/11/21",
                  6]
```

and a MySQL Table `models` like

[image]

now I am using this jQuery Ajax to insert the data into the `models` table

```
$('#upload-model').on('click', function(e){

   var serializedArr = JSON.stringify(arrLoadDb);
   var upload = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "assets/app/databaseSeeder.php",
                        data: {data:serializedArr},
                        cache: false
  });
```

and in `databaseSeeder.php` I have

```
<?php
session_start(); 
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'config.php';
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
$data = json_decode( $_POST['data'] );
$sql = "INSERT INTO `models` (mName, roadLength, powerLineLength, penstock, insCapacity, annFirmEnergy, costEnergy, footprint, costPerYear, eTarget, rorPriorities, species, disturbance, slider, date, userID ) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";       
   $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
   $stmt->bind_param( 'sssssssssssssssi', 
                            $data[0],
                            $data[1],
                            $data[2],
                            $data[3],
                            $data[4],
                            $data[5],
                            $data[6],
                            $data[7],
                            $data[8],
                            $data[9],
                            $data[10],
                            $data[11],
                            $data[12],
                            $data[13],
                            $data[14],
                            $data[15]
);

  $stmt->execute(); 
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
```

but it is not inserting any thing into database while all credential are correct

Comment: Anything in your error logs?

Comment: I tried getting erro by JSON .done() but I am getting all HTM from the page in the console insted of any error message!

Comment: On the PHP side check for errors, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: Your second from last is a date field, so might need to wrap in [str_to_date()](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php): `str_to_date($data[14], '%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: Make sure $data is an array `$data = json_decode( $_POST['data'] ,true);`

Answer (score 0):

you have 1 more db column than the data you're submitting. make sure that you either specify all fields before inserting or your insert statement specifies the fields you are inserting